# Trigonometric measuring equation. Need help at solving

Tags: trigonometry

So I had a math test and so far things went fine. Except from that one trigonometric problem where I wasn't able to score even 1 point. I'm also having a hard time finding something similar on the internet that's close to the trigonometric problem in the exam. Luckily, I still remember roughly all important numbers and words, so maybe someone is able to help me out.

> A road goes between the village $A$ and $D$, which are both on the
>   same horizontal plane. The road also goes through a tunnel, which
>   starting point is $B$ and ending point is $C$. Because $A$ and $D$ can't be
>   directly measured, there is a point $S$ on the same horizontal plane. The distance between $AS$ and $SD$ is:

$$AS = 1830 = a$$
$$SD = 1200 = b$$
$$\angle ASD = \alpha = 21.07^{\circ}$$
$$\angle CSD = \beta = 25.93^{\circ}$$
$$y = 108$$

> How long is the road between $A$ and $D$?

and

> How long is the tunnel between $B$ and $C$?

Does anyone how even a slight idea on how to approach this problem?

I mean, I would be able to calculate the missing sides, but I'm having a really hard time drawing the triangle to solve this problem.

Any input is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $y$ ?..

Comment: Somebody was so nice to edit my question in the correct format. Never used math stackexchange before, sorry for that.

Comment: No worries, I still feel there are some numbers missing, as we have no information on $B$ and not nearly enough information about $C$.

Comment: Can you make an image please?